# Compare .jpg files inside of a .txt file and merge data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

From a.txt-

```
/set03/V001/visible/I00875.jpg 333,212,354,254,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00955.jpg 469,224,524,348,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00955.jpg 392,212,424,276,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00773.jpg 343,218,369,263,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00773.jpg 357,216,381,264,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00773.jpg 276,204,296,246,0
/set03/V001/visible/I01236.jpg 229,207,249,233,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00484.jpg 324,191,344,240,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00484.jpg 315,194,337,246,0
```

Find matching .jpg files and merge the color codes to one line for each .img and put into a new file b.txt using Python-

```
/set03/V001/visible/I00875.jpg 333,212,354,254,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00955.jpg 469,224,524,348,0 392,212,424,276,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00773.jpg 343,218,369,263,0 357,216,381,264,0 276,204,296,246,0
/set03/V001/visible/I01236.jpg 229,207,249,233,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00484.jpg 324,191,344,240,0 315,194,337,246,0
```

Comment: Will the duplicates always be adjacent to each other in the input?

Comment: In this case, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using defaultdict set to list, you get the results. The version Python I used is version 3.7 (which keeps items in the same order as they were entered into the dictionary).

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

fin = open('f4.txt', 'r')

for line in fin:
    file, color = line.split()
    d[file].append(color)

for file, colors in d.items():
    print(file, ' '.join(colors))
```

Output is:

```
/set03/V001/visible/I00875.jpg 333,212,354,254,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00955.jpg 469,224,524,348,0 392,212,424,276,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00773.jpg 343,218,369,263,0 357,216,381,264,0 276,204,296,246,0
/set03/V001/visible/I01236.jpg 229,207,249,233,0
/set03/V001/visible/I00484.jpg 324,191,344,240,0 315,194,337,246,0
```

Edit: to print to an output file, you would need to open:

`fout = open('b.txt', 'w')`

And in the the for loop:

`fout.write(file + ' ' + ' '.join(colors) + '\n')`